# Discord.MessageAttachment() not attaching to embed

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So I am trying to attach an image to a discord embed (preferably as the thumbnail). The image is locally stored on my hard drive. I am currently doing it this way:

```js
attachment = await new discord.MessageAttachment('serverFavicon.png', 'favicon.png');
embed.setThumbnail(attachment);
```

and this returns this error and not send the embed:

```
(node:60598) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
embed.thumbnail.url: Could not interpret "{'attachment': 'serverFavicon.png', 'name': 'favicon.png'}" as string.
    at RequestHandler.execute (/Users/manders/Desktop/Bots/Minecraft Server Discord Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:154:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (/Users/manders/Desktop/Bots/Minecraft Server Discord Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:39:14)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:60598) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:60598) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

The strange thing is if I do

```js
message.channel.send('Image', attachment);
```

It will successfully send the image.

So I am wondering why it won't attach to the embed, but it can send to a channel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`setThumbnail`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=setThumbnail) only accepts a string (the URL of the image), not a `MessageAttachment`.

In your example, you can simply use the URL of the image:

```js
embed.setThumbnail('serverFavicon.png');
```

If you want to rename the image, you can attach the `MessageAttachment` when sending the message and use `attachment://image-name.png` for the thumbnail URL:

```js
// You also don't need to use await here; constructors can't be async
const attachment = new discord.MessageAttachment('serverFavicon.png', 'favicon.png');
embed.setThumbnail('attachment://favicon.png');

// ...
// Discord.js v12:
message.channel.send({embed, files: [attachment]});
// Discord.js v13:
message.channel.send({embeds: [embed], files: [attachment]});
```

See the [Discord developer docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#create-message-using-attachments-within-embeds) for more information on using attachments in embeds.